# adding Lightbox on image click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this cool html css card below, where I now need to have that if you click it, it shows a lightbox with multiple photos. I have tried multiple things before, but the problem is everything gets messed up when you do light box.

this is the code for the picture card alone. and this is the link to see it with me trying the light box. https://codepen.io/gianlucaas/pen/rNzBKVz
what am i doing wrong?

```js
 function myFunction() {
  var modelName = "Angela"
  var height = 'My name is Angela'
  var myImage = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633594708103-e6e41891b679?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1040&q=80"
    
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = modelName;
    document.getElementById("myHeight").innerHTML = height;
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = myImage;
  }
```

```css
.card-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.card-content-details {
  padding: 10px;
}

.card-content-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 15px;
}

.card-content-details,
.card-content-overlay {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card-content-details {
  transform: translateX(1000px);
  transition-duration: 800ms;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-content-overlay {
  background-color: #02010100;
  transition-duration: 800ms;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, background-color;
  transform: translateX(-1000px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-content-image {
  transition-duration: 800ms;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
 
}

.card-content:hover .card-content-image {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.card-content:hover .card-content-overlay,
.card-content:hover .card-content-details {
  transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.card-content:hover .card-content-overlay {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #00000000 81%, #000000ba 14%);
}

.card-content-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.card-content-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="card-content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="card-content-image" src="" id="myImg">
      <div class="card-content-details">
         <h4 class="card-content-title" id="myText"></h4>
        <p class="card-content-text" id="myHeight"></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: codepen link is not working

Comment: oh man. sorry, i didn't save it by accident. i will try to do it again.

Comment: @decpk ok i did it, you can try now

Answer (score 0):

You can begin by creating a html container on your file of your lightbox (which will be hidden) with inside the buttons (prev, next, close) and the  (empty for now).
When you launch the lightbox (with a js function that you'll have to create) you'll be display:block this html container (position: fixed; in CSS and with the highest z-index)

Comment: Consider editing your answer to include some code/script with your answer to make it more helpful.